# Facing issue in adding mutiple Struts actions

Tags: java, google-app-engine, struts2, xml-configuration, action-mapping

I am facing issue in displaying a struts action for result of `json` type. In the similar there is `LoginJson.action` which works fine. I do not understand where is the mistake. The error I could see is

```
Error 404 There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [RegisterJson] associated with context path [].
```

Here is my code :

[image] [image][image][image][image][image]![image][image]

Comment: Why you enter wrong URL?

Comment: sorry ! i did not get you. can you pls correct the url .. @RomanC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have configured action with name `RegsiterJson`  but in URL you entered `RegisterJson`, so it looks like a typo or you can redirect to the action

```
<action name="RegisterJson">
  <result type="redirectAction">RegsiterJson</result>
</action>
```